# ANTLR multiple alternatives error

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr

Wenn I try to execute ANTLR grammar I get the following exception:

*Decision can match input such as "DIGIT..LETTER" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2*

My grammar looks like this:

```
grammar twp3;
ALPHA   : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'); 
DIGIT :  ('0' .. '9');
LETTER  : ALPHA | '_';
identifier  :   LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT )*;
number  :  DIGIT+;
type    :   primitiveType  | identifier |('any' 'defined' 'by' identifier);
primitiveType   :   'int' | 'string' | 'binary' | 'any';
typedef :   structdef | sequencedef | uniondef | forwarddef;
field   :   'optional'? type identifier ';';
```

The problem is by multiple usage of identifier by type and field.

Please help me to correct my grammar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you're trying to parse the input `"abc"` (without the quotes). Now your `field` rule contains `type identifier`, and `type` can also match an `identifier`. So you could say that the parser should be able to match `identifier identifier`. But how should the input be "divided"? The parser could match `"a"` to the first `identifier` and `"bc"` to the second `identifier`. But it could also match `"ab"` to the first, and `"c"` to the second.

The fact that the parser can create more than one *parse* from a single input is the ambiguity in your grammar (the error message you encountered). And the cause of it is that you're trying to create identifiers at parse-time, while you should create them at lexer-time. So, if you create lexer tokens of `identifier` instead of parser tokens, all should be okay.

And your lexer should not be creating `ALPHA`, `DIGIT` and `LETTER` tokens. These rules should only be used by other lexer (so they should be marked as "fragment" rules).

Lastly, just like an identifier rule, you should make your `number` rule a lexer rule instead of a parser rule (lexer rules start with a capital, parser rules with a lower case letter):

```
grammar twp3;

type          : primitiveType  | Identifier | 'any' 'defined' 'by' Identifier;
primitiveType : 'int' | 'string' | 'binary' | 'any';
field         : 'optional'? type Identifier ';';

Identifier : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
Number     : DIGIT+;

fragment ALPHA  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'); 
fragment DIGIT  : ('0' .. '9');
fragment LETTER : ALPHA | '_';
```